# VBA Collection: Why does my collection get replaced with each iteration

Tags: vba, function, excel, collections

```
'Class ClsUser
Public User As String
Public Company As String

Public Function AddUser(ByVal UserName As String, ByVal CompanyName As String)
    User = UserName
    Company = CompanyName
End Function
```

In module

```
Public User_Collection As New Collection

Function Main()
    Dim User_Data As ClsUser
    Set User_Data = New ClsUser 
    Call Load_Collection(User_Data)
End Function

Function Load_Collection(ByRef ByRef oUser As ClsUser)
    Set oUser = New ClsUser
    Set User_Collection = New Collection

    Dim arr(1) As String
    arr(0) = "Jack"
    arr(1) = "Jill"
    For x = 0 to 1
        oUser.User = arr(x)
        User_Collection.Add oUser, oUser.User
    next
End Function
```

Whenever the oUser is updated, so is every item in the collection. The end result is a collection of items that are exactly the same. What am I doing wrong?

*Note: I have simplified the code to only show what is most relevant to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function Load_Collection(ByRef ByRef oUser As ClsUser)
Set oUser = New ClsUser
```

Here function input is oUser and next you set oUser as `New ClsUser`. In my opinion it doesn't have sense.

Comment: This is exactly the problem. Apparently, you must create a new oUser object every time you add new data. That new object is then added to the collection.
    `Set oUser = New ClsUser
    oUser.User = arr(x)`

Comment: I don't understand what will you do with this code, because this two line are exclude each other.

Comment: This code is about testing a collection object at its most basic form; to understand how it work. Now I can incorporate it into my program which is much more complex.

Comment: @Kahlan Liniel, you are correct, it doesn't make sense. Although I am still wondering why your answer 'makes sense', according to the OP, but my answer does not...lol :-) ? My answer addressed the problem you mentioned also - but it was not the reason for getting the same instances in OPs collection, which was the OPs original question. Weird. lol :-) +1 anyway

Comment: You were both correct, now that I looked at your answer more closely @Rusan. The piece I was missing was `Set oUser = new ClsUser`. I thought it only had to be defined once, but in reality it must be redefined each time you are creating a new object. Thanks for all your help both of you.

Comment: @Kahlan Yes. That's correct. Feel free to select an answer as accepted so other people can find the solution to similar problems. Liniel, sorry for the spam :)

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using a single instance of `oUser`.
In addition, this code has other problems.

In VBA functions have a return value. If they don't return values, you should use `Sub`s. This works...

```
Public User_Collection As New Collection

Sub Main()
    Dim User_Data As ClsUser
    Set User_Data = New ClsUser
    Call Load_Collection
End Sub

Sub Load_Collection()
    Dim oUser As ClsUser
    Set User_Collection = New Collection

    Dim arr(1) As String
    arr(0) = "Jack"
    arr(1) = "Jill"
    For x = 0 To 1
      Set oUser = New ClsUser
        oUser.User = arr(x)
        User_Collection.Add oUser, oUser.User
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This answer is inmaterial to the question I was asking. Yes, I should have used Sub instead of Function. The question was actually about why my collection of data was exactly the same.

Comment: @Kahlan I answered you question in the first line. The using of `Sub` was secondary. It comes under the *other problems with your code*. If you read my answer, you notice that I have moved the line (that made no sense) `Set oUser = New ClsUser` to within the loop, as this creates a new instance to add to the collection.